# How to determine file system type reliably under Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to be able to run a command which would print what exactly FAT version/subtype is a partition formatted in (FAT12/FAT16/FAT32/VFAT/exFAT)

Some guys suggests following command

```
# stat -f -c %T /boot/efi
msdos
```

or

```
# df -T | grep boot
/dev/sda2      vfat        262144     67916    194228  26% /boot/efi
```

here is what `stat` prints for exFAT

```
# stat -f -c %T /media/a1ex/7B57-DCAA/
fuseblk
```

These outputs look confusing, don't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vfat` is only to represent that it's a FAT partition, according to the partition table and fstab. `fdisk -l` will tell you the same thing as `df -T` or `mount`.

I wouldn't use `stat`, I would use `file /dev/sda2` or `parted /dev/sda -l` to get a better idea.

Side note: `fuseblk` is used for auto-mounted media. There is a clear difference between the `/boot/efi` and the `/media/...` example you showed.

Comment: `# file /dev/sda1` prints `/dev/sda1: block special` - so it is even more confusing. Luckily `parted -l` prints `FAT32` and it seems is exactly what I needed (btw, it prints partition info for all block devices, doesn't matter what path/device is specified). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a real answer to the question.

The `file -s` command does give info about the FAT type:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/nvme0n1p2

/dev/nvme0n1p2: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", sectors/cluster 2, reserved sectors 6654, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 1085440, sectors 204800 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 769, reserved 0x1, serial number 0xbe4b6aa0, unlabeled
```

the relevant part => `FAT (32 bit)`

Answer (score 0):

This command will do it:

`lsblk -o FSTYPE`

A more useful combination of flags might be:

`lsblk -o FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,TYPE,NAME`

```
FSTYPE      MOUNTPOINT TYPE  NAME
                       disk  sda
ntfs                   part  ├─sda1
ntfs                   part  └─sda2
            [SWAP]     disk  zram0
                       disk  nvme0n1
ext4        /boot      part  ├─nvme0n1p1
crypto_LUKS            part  └─nvme0n1p2
btrfs       /home      crypt   └─luks-69980091-6c68-42a0-adf9-4d7e07c7239f
```